# derivative of inverse function problems with proof

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inverse-function

**Theorem**

Let $f \colon U \to V$ be homeomorphism form open set U in normed space X, to open set V in normed set Y. Let  $a\in U$, $b=f(a)$, $f'(x_0) \colon X \to Y$ exists and it is isomorphism. Then the derivative $(f^{-1})'(b)$ exists and $(f^{-1})'(b) = (f'(a))^{-1}.$

**Proof in book**

Let $g=f^{-1}$
It is
\begin{equation*} 
f(a+x)-f(x)=f'(a)x+o(x)
\end{equation*}
We have to prove 
\begin{equation*} 
g(b+y)-f(b)-(f'(a))^{-1}y=o(y)
\end{equation*}
or
\begin{equation*}
\frac{g(y+b)-g(b)-(f'(a))^{-1}y}{||y||}  \to 0  \ { when } \  y\to0.
\end{equation*}

---

Set $x = g(y+b)-g(b)$ so

$x+a=g(y+b)$. We then have $f(x+a)=y+b$.

From this we obtain

\begin{equation}
y=f(a+x)-f(a)
\end{equation}

and so
$g(y+b)-g(b)=(f'(a))^{-1}*o(x)$
so it is enough to show

$\frac{||x||}{||y||} $

is bounded but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mixed up the variables. And you are trying to divide in a normed space, which may not be possible. I assume you mean to divide by the $\textit{norm}$ of $y$.

I am picking up where you left off:

Note first that there is a $c>0$ such that $\frac{\|f'(x_0)(x-x_0)\|}{\|x-x_0\|}>c$ in a suitably small neighborhood of $x_0$ because $f'(x_0)$ is invertible.

Now, by the reverse triangle inequality,

$\underset{x\to x_0}\liminf\frac{\|f(x)-f(x_0)\|}{\|x-x_0\|}\ge\underset{x\to x_0}\liminf  \left|\frac{\|f'(x_0)(x-x_0)\|}{\|x-x_0\|}-\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)}{\|x-x_0\|}\right|=\underset{x\to x_0}\liminf  \left|\frac{\|f'(x_0)(x-x_0)\|}{\|x-x_0\|}\right|\ge c\tag 1$

Now, use the continuity of $f,\ f^{-1}$ and $f'(x_0)^{-1}$ and apply the result in $(1)$:

$\underset{y\to y_0}\lim\frac{f^{-1}(y)-f^{-1}(y_0)-(f'(x_0))^{-1}(y-y_0)}{\|y-y_0\|}=\underset{x\to x_0}\lim\frac{x-x_0-(f'(x_0))^{-1}(f(x)-f(x_0))}{\|f(x)-f(x_0\|}=$

$\underset{x\to x_0}\lim\left(-f'(x_0)^{-1}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-(f'(x_0)(x-x_0)}{\|x-x_0\|}\right)\frac{\|x-x_0\|}{\|f(x)-f(x_0)\|}\right)=0\tag 2$